# how to wait before spawning inside while loop spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nodes, wait

The goal of the code is to spawn cards until the sum of the cards hits 17. The code works fine in that case, but I want it to wait 1 second before spawning the other card. The code currently spawns all the cards (and stops until 17 is reached) at once, which I don't want. Here's a simplified version, for reference it is in touchesBegan in SpriteKit:

```
else if standLabel.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
                let waitForCard = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
                while dealerCardValues.sum() <= 16 {
                    self.run(waitForCard)

                    spawnCard()
                    

                }
```

The wait for duration doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "The wait for duration doesn't work" Yes it does, but it doesn't have any effect on _your code_. It doesn't cause your code to magically stop in the middle.

Comment: How does `dealCardValues.sum()` change during that loop? If we know how many times this loop will run, just use `DispatchQueue` with a delay increasing for each index of the loop. If this value is unknown, you could recursively a function inside itself with a delay.

Comment: Or maybe you can use `SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1), SKAction.run { ... }])`? Not too sure for your needs.

Comment: @matt, ok .., then what can I do to get to my desired result?

Comment: @George, the function inside spawnCard does that, the code doesn't exactly show it since I simplified it

Comment: @George, tried out the SKAction method, doesn't work though.

Comment: @George, not familiar with DispatchQueue & recursion .. how do they work?

Comment: @jhonalbert I mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47358187/9607863) for `for` loops. Since you have a `while` loop instead, try use a function containing `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter ...` and call the function inside the closure (which is after some time has passed). It's quite difficult to explain in these comments, so provide more detail in your question and someone may write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Timer for this. The timer is called every 1 second, which runs the `spawnCard()` function as well as adding 1 to the counter variable. Once  `counter` has reached 17 we invalidate it to stop it firing again.

So replace this code:

```
let waitForCard = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
            while dealerCardValues.sum() <= 16 {
                self.run(waitForCard)

                spawnCard()
```

With this:

```
  var counter = 1
  
  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [self] timer in
    
    counter += 1
    spawnCard()
    
    if counter == 17 {
      timer.invalidate()
    }
    
  }
```